# apache | FilesMatch and Indexes - hide all files with exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I have folder with Indexes option. I have hide all files in listing directory except (jpe?g|pdf|bmp|png|html|css).

But my config do not working). Help me,please fix it.

```
<Directory /home/*/Downloads>
    AllowOverride All
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec


<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|jpe?g|pdf|bmp|png|html|css)$">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "">
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Filesmatch>

</Directory>
```

p.s. Apache 2.2

Comment: @anubhava for any (as example http://domain.tld/~user/Donwloads/)

Comment: @anubhava 403 forbidden, in log - client denied by server configuration: /home/user/Downloads/

Comment: That is due to your `<FilesMatch "">` block in the end. It is unclear what exactly you're trying to do here using all these `Limit` and `LimitExcept` directives.

Comment: @anubhava remove Limit..  if i write `...
<FilesMatch ".(rpm)$">
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Filesmatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|jpe?g|pdf|bmp|png|html|css)$">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>
</Directory>` just hide .rpm only, i want hide all except grpahics files

Answer (score 2):

Change the order of your `FilesMatch` directives, i.e. block everything first then allow certain type of files later:

```
<FilesMatch "">
    Order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Filesmatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|jpe?g|pdf|bmp|png|html|css)$">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Nothing. 403 Forbidden